# for a polydisperse polymer, why is its weight average molecular weight always bigger than its number average molecular weight?

Tags: polymers

The statement comes from my lecture slides on polymers. I hope someone can show me the maths proof for the inequality. 
I will try come up with the proof, too. It is actually a maths question:D Here is the basic definition for the two average weights: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Molar_mass_distribution

Comment: Surely it's axiomatic that for a positive number (in this case the molecular mass), that the squared value is larger? By definition if a polymer is described as polydisperse, the PDI is >1, so Mw must be greater than Mn

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Mathematics has many examples of identities and concepts which are extremely powerful due to their simplicity, such as the [pigeonhole principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle) and the [triangle inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_inequality). One such identity will guide us through the problem.

We start with the very innocent identity, that for a real number $z$, the following is true:

$$z^2 \geq 0$$

Now let $z = x-y$. We have:
$$(x-y)^2 \geq 0$$
$$x^2 -2xy + y^2 \geq 0$$
$$x^2 + y^2 \geq 2xy $$
$$\frac{x^2 + y^2}{2} \geq xy $$

Now this last inequality has a very powerful interpretation. To show it more clearly, we can replace $x^2$ with $a$ and $y^2$ with $b$, yielding:

$$\frac{a + b}{2} \geq \sqrt{ab} $$

In words, the arithmetic mean of two positive real numbers will always be greater than or equal to their geometric mean. This is called the [AM-GM inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequality_of_arithmetic_and_geometric_means), and it often shows up in the most surprising of places.

---

Let's get started. We define the *number average* molecular weight ($M_{n}$) and the *weight average* molecular weight ($M_{w}$) of a polydisperse polymer mixture as the following, respectively:

$$M_{n}=\frac  {\sum\limits_{i} N_{i}M_{i}}{\sum\limits_{i} N_{i}} \quad , \quad M_{w}=\frac  {\sum\limits_{i} N_{i} M_{i}^2 }{\sum\limits_{i} N_{i}M_{i}}$$

We then define the dispersity index $Đ$ (or $PDI$) as:

$$Đ = \frac{M_w}{M_n} = \frac{\sum\limits_{i} N_{i} M_{i}^2 \sum\limits_{i} N_{i}}{(\sum\limits_{i} N_{i}M_{i})^2}$$

To make things easier, let us start by analyzing the first non-trivial case ($i=2$):

$$Đ = \frac{M_w}{M_n} = \frac{(N_{1} M_{1}^2 + N_{2} M_{2}^2)(N_{1} + N_{2}) }{(N_{1} M_{1} + N_{2} M_{2})^2}$$

We multiply the bracketed terms and expand the binomial to obtain:

$$Đ = \frac{M_w}{M_n} = \frac{N_{1}^2 M_{1}^2 + N_{2}^2 M_{2}^2 + N_{1}N_{2}M_{1}^2 + N_{1}N_{2}M_{2}^2}{N_{1}^2 M_{1}^2 + 2N_{1}N_{2}M_{1}M_{2} + N_{2}^2 M_{2}^2}$$

Rearranging the terms slightly:

$$Đ = \frac{M_w}{M_n} = \frac{N_{1}^2 M_{1}^2 + N_{2}^2 M_{2}^2 + \color{#ff0000}{N_{1}N_{2}(M_{1}^2 + M_{2}^2)}}{N_{1}^2 M_{1}^2 + N_{2}^2 M_{2}^2 + \color{#0000ff}{2N_{1}N_{2}M_{1}M_{2}}}$$

Notice that the terms in the numerator and denominator match except for the coloured parts.

Here is where the magic happens. From the AM-GM inequality, we must have:

$$x^2 + y^2 \geq 2xy \quad \Rightarrow \quad M_{1}^2 + M_{2}^2 \geq 2M_{1}M_{2}$$

We then replace the term $(M_{1}^2 + M_{2}^2)$ in the numerator with the term $2M_{1}M_{2}$. By doing so, the new numerator is smaller than or equal to the old numerator. Thus:

$$Đ = \frac{M_w}{M_n} = \frac{N_{1}^2 M_{1}^2 + N_{2}^2 M_{2}^2 + \color{#ff0000}{N_{1}N_{2}(M_{1}^2 + M_{2}^2)}}{N_{1}^2 M_{1}^2 + N_{2}^2 M_{2}^2 + \color{#0000ff}{2N_{1}N_{2}M_{1}M_{2}}} \geq \frac{N_{1}^2 M_{1}^2 + N_{2}^2 M_{2}^2 + \color{#0000ff}{2N_{1}N_{2}M_{1}M_{2}}}{N_{1}^2 M_{1}^2 + N_{2}^2 M_{2}^2 + \color{#0000ff}{2N_{1}N_{2}M_{1}M_{2}}}=1$$

$$Đ = \frac{M_w}{M_n} \geq 1$$

---

What about the next non-trivial case ($i=3$)? We have:

$$Đ = \frac{M_w}{M_n} = \frac{(N_{1} M_{1}^2 + N_{2} M_{2}^2 + N_{3} M_{3}^2)(N_{1} + N_{2} + N_{3}) }{(N_{1} M_{1} + N_{2} M_{2} + N_{3} M_{3})^2}$$

Multiplying everything out and performing the appropriate arrangements yields:

$$Đ = \frac{M_w}{M_n} = \frac{N_{1}^2 M_{1}^2 + N_{2}^2 M_{2}^2 + N_{3} M_{3}^2 + \color{#ff0000}{N_{1}N_{2}(M_{1}^2 + M_{2}^2) + N_{1}N_{3}(M_{1}^2 + M_{3}^2) + N_{2}N_{3}(M_{2}^2 + M_{3}^2)}}{N_{1}^2 M_{1}^2 + N_{2}^2 M_{2}^2 + N_{3}^2M_{3}^2 + \color{#0000ff}{2N_{1}N_{2}M_{1}M_{2} + 2N_{1}N_{3}M_{1}M_{3} + 2N_{2}N_{3}M_{2}M_{3}}}$$

This time, we can use the AM-GM inequality thrice:

$$M_{1}^2 + M_{2}^2 \geq 2M_{1}M_{2} \quad , \quad M_{1}^2 + M_{3}^2 \geq 2M_{1}M_{3} \quad , \quad M_{2}^2 + M_{3}^2 \geq 2M_{2}M_{3}$$

The end result is the same:

$$Đ = \frac{M_w}{M_n} = \frac{N_{1}^2 M_{1}^2 + N_{2}^2 M_{2}^2 + N_{3} M_{3}^2 + \color{#ff0000}{N_{1}N_{2}(M_{1}^2 + M_{2}^2) + N_{1}N_{3}(M_{1}^2 + M_{3}^2) + N_{2}N_{3}(M_{2}^2 + M_{3}^2)}}{N_{1}^2 M_{1}^2 + N_{2}^2 M_{2}^2 + N_{3}^2M_{3}^2 + \color{#0000ff}{2N_{1}N_{2}M_{1}M_{2} + 2N_{1}N_{3}M_{1}M_{3} + 2N_{2}N_{3}M_{2}M_{3}}} $$
$$\geq \frac{N_{1}^2 M_{1}^2 + N_{2}^2 M_{2}^2 + N_{3} M_{3}^2 + \color{#0000ff}{2N_{1}N_{2}M_{1}M_{2} + 2N_{1}N_{3}M_{1}M_{3} + 2N_{2}N_{3}M_{2}M_{3}}}{N_{1}^2 M_{1}^2 + N_{2}^2 M_{2}^2 + N_{3}^2M_{3}^2 + \color{#0000ff}{2N_{1}N_{2}M_{1}M_{2} + 2N_{1}N_{3}M_{1}M_{3} + 2N_{2}N_{3}M_{2}M_{3}}} = 1$$

$$Đ = \frac{M_w}{M_n} \geq 1$$

---

Now stating the general case:

$$Đ = \frac{M_w}{M_n} = \frac{\sum\limits_{i} N_{i} M_{i}^2 \sum\limits_{i} N_{i}}{(\sum\limits_{i} N_{i}M_{i})^2} = \frac{\sum\limits_{i} N_{i}^2 M_{i}^2  + \color{#ff0000}{\sum\limits_{i,j\ (j>i)} N_{i}N_{j}(M_{i}^2 + M_{j}^2)}}{\sum\limits_{i} N_{i}^2 M_{i}^2 + \color{#0000ff}{2\sum\limits_{i,j\ (j>i)} N_{i}N_{j}M_{i}M_{j}}} \geq \frac{\sum\limits_{i} N_{i}^2 M_{i}^2  + \color{#0000ff}{2\sum\limits_{i,j\ (j>i)} N_{i}N_{j}M_{i}M_{j}}}{\sum\limits_{i} N_{i}^2 M_{i}^2 + \color{#0000ff}{2\sum\limits_{i,j\ (j>i)} N_{i}N_{j}M_{i}M_{j}}}=1$$

$$Đ = \frac{M_w}{M_n} \geq 1$$

Comment: I was thinking about explaining it in terms of the [Cauchy-Schwarz inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality), but your way is more convincing.